# Using KafkaSpout, ack-ing a tuple twice causes timeouts?

Tags: apache-storm

My topology uses the default `KafkaSpout` implementation. In some very controlled testing, I noticed the spout was failing tuples even though none of my bolts were failing any tuples and I was certain all messages were being fully processed well within my configured timeout.

I also noticed that (due to some sub-classing structure with my bolts), one of my bolts was ack-ing tuples twice. When I fixed this, the spout stopped failing tuples.

Sorry that this is more than a sanity check than a question, but does this make sense?  I don't see why ack-ing the same tuple instance twice would cause the Spout to register timeouts, but it seems it was in my case?

Comment: Bam!  We had this exact same problem!  I was of the opinion that we 'could' ack more than once.  We had an edge case where we were getting maybe one or two during a 10 minute period.  Couldn't figure it out.  When we fixed the extra ack, it all went away.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does make sense.

Storm tracks all of the acks (direct and indirect) for a tuple emitted by a spout in an odd but effective manner.  I'm not sure of the exact algorithm, but it entails repeatedly XOR'ing what was originally the spout-emitted tuple ID with the ID's of subsequent anchored tuple ID's.  each of those subsequent ID's is XOR'ed twice - once when the tuple is anchored and once when the tuple is acked.  When the results of an XOR is all zero's, then the assumption is that each anchor was matched by an ack and the original spout-emitted tuple has finished processing.

By ack'ing some tuples more than once, you made it seem that some of the spout-emitted tuples were not finished completely (because an odd number of XOR's will never zero out).

Comment: So lemme ask a question.  We had this happening on an edge case, but eventually they would all clear out.  How does storm know when a tuple is completed?  Since the topology itself sends the emits, does it wait a period of time before it says, "I haven't heard anything in a while, it must be done?".  For example, I have 2 bolts and only 1/2 are emitted to the second bolt.  For a tuple that only goes to the first bolt and is properly acked, When does storm conclude the tuple is finished?

Comment: It is a matter of timing.  As soon as all of the anchor's have been "closed off" by an ACK the processing is assumed to be complete.  In your case, you'd want to be sure to ACK the inbound tuple only after you anchor the outbound tuple.  In that way, you ensure that there's always an un-ACKed anchor if there's more processing to do.

Comment: So are you saying you have to emit before you ack?